# How to improve my friend list MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big MySQL query which actually returns the good set of result but it is quite slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  username,
  user.id as uid,
  email,
  ui.gender,
  ui.country,
  ui.birthday,
  IF( last_activity_date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, 1, 0) as is_online,
  p.thumb_url,
  friend_request.id as sr_id,
  IF( ul.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as st_love,
  DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT( birthday, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT( birthday, '00-%m-%d')) AS age

FROM friend_request

JOIN user ON (user.`id` = friend_request.`to_user_id`
                   OR
                   user.`id` = friend_request.`from_user_id`)
              AND user.`id` != '$user_id'
              AND friend_request.`status` = '1'

JOIN user_info ui ON user.`id` = ui.`user_id`

JOIN photo p ON ui.`main_photo` = p.`id`

LEFT JOIN user_love ul ON ul.`to_user_id` = user.`id`
                      AND ul.`from_user_id` = $user_id

WHERE (friend_request.`to_user_id` = '$user_id'
   OR  friend_request.`from_user_id` = '$user_id')
ORDER BY friend_request.id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

"$user_id" is the id of the logged-in user.

Here is the table structure of "friend_request" :

```
CREATE TABLE `friend_request` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `seen` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from_user_id` (`from_user_id`),
  KEY `to_user_id` (`to_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Can you help me to improve this query?

I have not copied the table structure of the other tables because, after some tests, the "optimization issue" seems to come from the friend_request table.

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

Here is what "EXPLAIN" gives me :

[image]

Comment: Consider providing a data set and desired result set.

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN. (Of course you have to switch tables left <-> right also...) That's a real improvement in readability! (Most people have enough problems with left join, and get too confused when it comes to right join...)

Comment: Are you calling this from an application? Could probably do some of the business logic (all the if/then statements and date conversions) in your application code and pass a parameterized list to MySql to relieve some of the processing on the database. And I agree with @jarlh to use left joins instead of right.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, I have updated my original post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @ragerory yes, I use this query in an application. If I remove the "IF" statements, the query still takes some time to load, even if it saves some ms.

Comment: I think you just changed the `right join` to a `left join` without moving their subjects (the tables on either side). I think this is not what @jarlh meant.

Comment: Normally, this kind of query would involve a UNION, and not much else. Just sayin'.

Comment: @TommyBravo, correct, left hand and right hand tables must be switched also.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the query plan or try using the key word `Explain` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html so that you can find what parts of your query are taking the longest and optimize them.

Things that jump out to me:

1) You may need to reduce your joins, or optimize them

2) You might need some indexes

3) You have an `OR` statement in your `where` clause, which *may* affect the cache query plan, I have seen an `Or` cause issues with query caching in tsql.  Not sure if that would affect mysql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

edit: formatting, found out the photo table join was necessary for the data that was being selected

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
1) -> is linked to the second IF statement of my query. Per the suggestion of another user here, I am working on moving the IF statements out of the query, so I will not need this part of the query anymore. It could save some ms.
2) I already have some indexes on the tables. But maybe I could improve this part too.

Comment: @fraxool the real key thing here is to use the `Explain` keyword, every query has to be optimized with more information than you have provided, and the explain key work will take those things into account (indexes, types of joins,, etc).  We are having to play guess and check without being about to use it.

Comment: I have just edited my original post with the result of "EXPLAIN".

Comment: is there any reason why you do a LEFT JOIN on the users table? I would have expected a normal JOIN. And what is the GROUP BY used for?

Comment: @Olli thanks for your suggestion! By updating my query without the GROUP BY and by replacing my LEFT JOIN (which was useless) by a normal join, my query is actually faster!

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the query like this. (I'd also qualify the references to *all* columns in the query, `username`, `email`, `last_activity_date`). I'd also be doing this as a prepared statement with bind placeholders, rather than including the `$user_id` variable into the SQL text.  We're assuming that the contents of `$user_id` is known to be "safe", or has been properly escaped, to avoid SQL injection.

```
  SELECT username
       , user.id  AS uid
       , email
       , ui.gender
       , ui.country
       , ui.birthday
       , IFNULL(( last_activity_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR),0) AS is_online
       , p.thumb_url
       , sr.id                                       AS sr_id
       , ul.id IS NOT NULL                           AS st_love
       , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,ui.birthday,DATE(NOW())) AS age
    FROM (
           ( SELECT frf.id
                  , frf.to_user_id   AS user_id
               FROM friend_request frf
              WHERE frf.to_user_id   <> '$user_id'
                AND frf.from_user_id  = '$user_id'
                AND frf.status = '1'
              ORDER BY frf.id DESC
              LIMIT 30
            )
            UNION ALL
            ( SELECT frt.id
                   , frt.from_user_id AS user_id
                FROM friend_request frt
               WHERE frt.from_user_id <> '$user_id'
                 AND frt.to_user_id    = '$user_id'
                 AND frt.status = '1'
               ORDER BY frt.id DESC
               LIMIT 30
            )
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 30
         ) sr
    JOIN user ON user.id = sr.user_id
    JOIN user_info ui ON ui.user_id = user.id
    JOIN photo p ON p.id = ui.main_photo
    LEFT
    JOIN user_love ul
      ON ul.to_user_id = user.id
     AND ul.from_user_id = '$user_id'

   ORDER BY sr.id DESC
   LIMIT 30
```

NOTES:

The inline view `sr` is intended to get at most 30 rows from friend_request, ordered by `id` descending (like the original query.)

It looks like the original query is intending to find rows where the specified `$user_id` is in either the `from_` or `to_` column.

Older versions of MySQL can generated some pretty obnoxious execution plans for queries involving `OR` predicates for JOIN operations. The usual workaround for that is to use a `UNION ALL` or `UNION` operation of the return from two separate SELECT statements... each SELECT can be optimized to use an appropriate index.

Once we have that resultset from `sr`, the rest of the query is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I just have a SQL Syntax error with your query and I can't really find from where it is : `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS age FROM ((SELECT frf.id, frf.to_user_id AS user_id FROM friend_request' at line 11`

Comment: Ooops.  It's just missing a closing paren  before `AS age`.

Comment: Just a last one! `#1054 - Unknown column 'fr.user_id' in 'on clause'`. Can you help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ooops. That looks like it should be `sr.user_id`, a reference to the `user_id` column returned from **`sr`**... that seems like what we would want to match on.